# Dose following code cause memory leak in javascript?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

Clearly, two functions of the same name are declared in this example.And the result is that the back function covers the previous function.

```
function addSomeNumber(num) {return num + 100;}
function addSomeNumber(num) {return num + 200;}
```

Comment: Why would this cause a memory leak?

Comment: Maybe you should review https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management.  Scroll down to Garbage Collection.

Comment: in js, a function name is like a pointer. So I think the back function will redirecting to an new area of memory.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't cause a memory leak.